# Why fixed-sized slices are not cheaper to allocate than variable-sized bytes.Buffer?

Tags: performance, go, memory-management, heap-memory

Here is my test code:

```golang
package app

import (
    "bytes"
    "testing"
)

const ALLOC_SIZE = 64 * 1024

func BenchmarkFunc1(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        v := make([]byte, ALLOC_SIZE)
        fill(v, '1', 0, ALLOC_SIZE)
    }
}

func BenchmarkFunc2(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        b := new(bytes.Buffer)
        b.Grow(ALLOC_SIZE)
        fill(b.Bytes(), '2', 0, ALLOC_SIZE)
    }
}

func fill(slice []byte, val byte, start, end int) {
    for i := start; i < end; i++ {
        slice = append(slice, val)
    }
}
```

Result:

```
at 19:05:47 ❯ go test -bench . -benchmem -gcflags=-m
# app [app.test]
./main_test.go:25:6: can inline fill
./main_test.go:10:6: can inline BenchmarkFunc1
./main_test.go:13:7: inlining call to fill
./main_test.go:20:9: inlining call to bytes.(*Buffer).Grow
./main_test.go:21:15: inlining call to bytes.(*Buffer).Bytes
./main_test.go:21:7: inlining call to fill
./main_test.go:10:21: b does not escape
./main_test.go:12:12: make([]byte, ALLOC_SIZE) escapes to heap
./main_test.go:20:9: BenchmarkFunc2 ignoring self-assignment in bytes.b.buf = bytes.b.buf[:bytes.m·3]
./main_test.go:17:21: b does not escape
./main_test.go:19:11: new(bytes.Buffer) does not escape
./main_test.go:25:11: slice does not escape
# app.test
/var/folders/45/vh6dxx396d590hxtz7_9_smmhqf0sq/T/go-build1328509211/b001/_testmain.go:35:6: can inline init.0
/var/folders/45/vh6dxx396d590hxtz7_9_smmhqf0sq/T/go-build1328509211/b001/_testmain.go:43:24: inlining call to testing.MainStart
/var/folders/45/vh6dxx396d590hxtz7_9_smmhqf0sq/T/go-build1328509211/b001/_testmain.go:43:42: testdeps.TestDeps{} escapes to heap
/var/folders/45/vh6dxx396d590hxtz7_9_smmhqf0sq/T/go-build1328509211/b001/_testmain.go:43:24: &testing.M{...} escapes to heap
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
pkg: app
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
BenchmarkFunc1-8            8565            118348 ns/op          393217 B/op          4 allocs/op
BenchmarkFunc2-8           23332             53043 ns/op           65536 B/op          1 allocs/op
PASS
ok      app     2.902s
```

My assumption was using fixed-sized slice created by `make` is way cheaper than `bytes.Buffer`, because the compiler might be able to know the size of memory required to be allocated at the compile-time. Using `bytes.Buffer` looks something like runtime-thing. However, the result is not what I have expected to be.

Any explaination on this?

Comment: Note that "fixed-sized slice" is not a thing. In fact, a slice is effectively defined by the fact that it is _not_ fixed sized.  I think what you mean is simply "pre-allocated slice".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are confusing capacity and length of slices.

```
v := make([]byte, ALLOC_SIZE)
```

v is now a slice with length 64k and capacity 64k. Appending anything to this slice forces Go to copy the backing array into a new, larger one.

```
b := new(bytes.Buffer)
b.Grow(ALLOC_SIZE)
v := b.Bytes()
```

Here, v is a slice with length zero and capacity 64k. You can append 64k bytes to this slice without any reallocation, because it is initially empty but the 64k backing array is ready to be used.

In summary, you are comparing a slice that is already filled to capacity to an empty slice with the same capacity.

To make a fair comparison change your first benchmark to allocate an empty slice as well:

```
func BenchmarkFunc1(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        v := make([]byte, 0, ALLOC_SIZE) // note the three argument form
        fill(v, '1', 0, ALLOC_SIZE)
    }
}
```

```
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: foo
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10210U CPU @ 1.60GHz
BenchmarkFunc1-8           23540             51990 ns/op           65536 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkFunc2-8           24939             45096 ns/op           65536 B/op          1 allocs/op
```

The relationship between slices, arrays, length, and capacity is explained in great detail in https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro

Comment: Thank you for the clarified answer! Let me ask one more thing: why is using `bytes.Buffer` is slightly faster than using just `make`? I have just read the code, but the both also uses `make` internally, so I still don't understand it. I tried changing `ALLOC_SIZE` to `1024 * 1024`, then the difference was huge.